# How to shift non circularly in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, shift

I am trying to shift non circularly in MATLAB so even if I shift outside of the index it will add 0s to correct it. I tried following the answer in [How do I shift columns (left or right) in a matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63320433/how-do-i-shift-columns-left-or-right-in-a-matrix) but had no success.

```
data = [1 2 3 4 5; 11 12 13 14 15; 21 22 23 24 25; 31 32 33 34 35]
d = 3; % shift; positive/negative for right/left
result = zeros(size(data), 'like', data); % preallocate with zeros
result(:,max(1,1+d):min(end,end+d)) = data(:,max(1,1-d):min(end,end-d)); % write values
```

In my output results is nothing but the same size but all zeroes

Desired output:

```
 0     0     0     1     2    3      4      5  
 0     0     0     11    12   13     14     15 
 0     0     0     21    22   23     24     25
 0     0     0     31    32   33     34     35
```

Comment: It works for me. Can you verify that the intermediate results are correct?

Comment: @beaker, it does not work for me (R2016a). The matrix is shifted and padded with zeros all right but it is truncated at the size of the original matrix (i.e. the shifted columns are dropped).

Comment: @Hoki Ah, the question said that the OP was getting an array of the same size but all zeros. I was confused. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by creating a matrix `result`, the final size, filled with zeros, then copying the original `data` into the final `result`, making sure you place the data at the right indices.

What you have in your example code is not right for what you ask. If I run it,the final result is padded fine but truncated at the size of the original `data` matrix. This is how some matrix are shifted (with the shifted columns dropped altogether), but that's not what you asked.

A simple way to do it, is to create a padding matrix of the proper size, then simply concatenate it with your original `data` matrix. This can be done as below:

```
%% Initial data
data = [1 2 3 4 5; 11 12 13 14 15; 21 22 23 24 25; 31 32 33 34 35] ;
d = 3 ;

%% shift and pad with zeros
nrows   = size(data,1) ;            % Number of rows in [data]
pad     = zeros( nrows , abs(d) ) ; % create padding matrix
if d>0
    result = [pad data] ; % Concatenate the filler matrix on the left
else
    result = [data pad] ; % Concatenate the filler matrix on the right
end
```

And just to be sure:

```
>> result
result =
     0     0     0     1     2     3     4     5
     0     0     0    11    12    13    14    15
     0     0     0    21    22    23    24    25
     0     0     0    31    32    33    34    35
```

---

If you want to reuse the same way than in your example code, you have to adjust it a bit to allow for the new columns:

```
%% create result and copy data
result = zeros( size(data,1) , size(data,2)+abs(d) ) ;
colStart = max(1,1+d) ;
result(:,colStart:colStart+size(data,2)-1) = data ;
```

This will create the same `result` matrix as above.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped. I did the same thing with another case, data = [1 2 3 4 5; 0 0 13 14 15; 0 0 23 24 25; 31 32 33 34 35] ; and am trying to shift the rows in 2 &3 to the left but instead of shifting it just adds zeroes to the left instead of doing the shift and adding the zeroes @hoki
with an expected output of [1 2 3 4 5 ; 13 14 15 0 0 ; 23 24 25 0 0 ; 31 32 33 34 35] ;

Comment: This is not "_the same thing_" with another case, it's a completely different problem. In your comment you are asking how to shift only a subset of rows (and this time without changing the size of the result matrix). I recommend you post a fresh new question for that, it won't be possible to answer both (different) problems on the same post.

Comment: Okay, will do. Thank you